# Retrieve Variable form Render Partial Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am in the process of trying to clean a long page by cutting it into sections and using render partial for the various sections. So far this has cleaned the page and increased readability, but I have one small issue.

I have my main index page and I have a section that loops through a customers orders and a section that show there user accounts ie:

```
$this->renderPartial('engineer_files/engineer_order', 
    array(
        'model' => $model,
        'orderServices' => $orderServices,
        'items' => $items,
        'extras' => $extras
    )
);

$this->renderPartial('engineer_files/rad',
    array(
        'model' => $model,
        'orderServices' => $orderServices,
        'items' => $items,
        'extras' => $extras,
        'servicesDp' => $servicesDp,
        'packageId' => $packageId
    )
);
```

Within the page engineer_order I have the following

```
$packageId = $services->service_id;
```

However I do not seem to be able to access this variable within the rad page. As you can see I have tried passing the variable in the render partial. If I declare the variable on the index page ie

```
$this->renderPartial('engineer_files/engineer_order',
    array(
        'model' => $model,
        'orderServices' => $orderServices,
        'items' => $items,
        'extras' => $extras
    )
);

$packageId = 2;

$this->renderPartial('engineer_files/rad',
    array(
        'model' => $model,
        'orderServices' => $orderServices,
        'items' => $items,
        'extras' => $extras,
        'servicesDp' => $servicesDp,
        'packageId' => $packageId
    )
);
```

Then the variable is accessible and usable, but I would ideally like to know how to declare a variable in one render partial and then pass this same variable to another render partial.
Many thanks

Comment: I have no idea how yii works, but what if you assign the variable that you want to $_SESSION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a variable in a renderPartial and then somehow use that same variable outside that view. Do you really have to create that variable inside `engineer_order` ?

Because the thing you can do is create the variable in the `index` page before you render anything else and then pass that variable to both renderPartials.

```
$myVar = 'bla';

$this->renderPartial('engineer_files/engineer_order',
    array('myVar' => $myVar)
);

$this->renderPartial('engineer_files/rad',
    array('myVar' => $myVar)
);
```

Comment: That's slightly annoying. Unfortunately I need to create the variable in engineer_order as I loop through the services and this is where the `$packageId` is set. As it's obviously not possible to do what I need, I have simply put all subsequent renderpartials in the engineer_order file itself, so that the variable can be passed. Many thanks for your time and expertise.